# Drift chat doesn't open after scroll

Tags: javascript, php, drift

I'm using a third party chat plugin on my site from [www.drift.com](http://www.drift.com).

I have issue on iOS devices. After page scroll, chat doesn't open on first touch. I have to touch it several times to open it (before scroll it works fine).
I embeded chat with javascript snippet which I copied from drift config.
Same problem drift have on their site.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Please add what you've attempted in your post

Comment: If possible try to add the example